# Passing Object in ng-repeat to another page to display its contents

Tags: html, mysql, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am working on a project using MySQL, Angular, Express, and Node. I have a list of objects in a ng-repeat and when I click a specific item I would like to pass the clicked object to another page and show the object's properties through angular.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class = "panel panel-info" ng-repeat="job in job">
    <div class = "panel-heading clickable">
        <h1 class = "panel-title">{{job.title}}</h1>
        <span class = "pull-right"><i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class = "panel-body">
        <!--This will soon be the place where the Students information is placed by NodeJS-->
        <!--<p style = "text-decoration: underline"> Job Title  <p>-->
        <p> {{job.description}} </p>
        <p> {{job.first_name}} {{job.last_name}}</p>
        <p> {{job.location}} </p>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class=" col-sm-15">
                <button onclick="location.href='jobPage.html';" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Apply</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
    soopControllers.controller("landingController",

function ($scope, $http){
    $scope.formData = {};

    $http.get('/api/jobLanding')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.job = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });

    //I want this function to get the job and send it to another page
    $scope.getJob = function(){
        $http.post('/api/job', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.users = data;
                //$location.redirect();
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data){
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS applications work the same way as regular web sites when it comes to navigation. The difference is that instead of sending a request to the server to go to the new URL, the router intercepts the location change, and goes to a route. The controller (or the resolve function) of that route then gets what it needs to display.

So, what you need in your ng-repeat instead of your button is

```
<a ng-href="#/job/{{ job.id }}">Apply</a>
```

And you then need a route mapped to the path `/job/:jobId`.

In the controller of this route, you'll then do something like

```
$http.get('/api/job/' + $routeParams.jobId).then(function(response) {
    $scope.job = response.data;
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! Just curious because I am new to the MEAN stack, what would the SQL query to grab the job by the id number look like within that route for /job/:jobId?

Comment: You're confused. A route is a client-side, angular thing. Angular doesn't do SQL queries. What sits behind the URL ''/api/job/{jobId}" in your backend is what needs to do a SQL query. Something like `select * from job where id = :jobId`.

Comment: yes that's what I meant. I just used the wrong terminology. I am going to test.

Answer (score 0):

How about using ng-click on the repeated element and extract that element in your display/routed page.

```
<div ng-controller="plandingController"
     class = "panel panel-info" 
     ng-repeat="job in job"
     ng-click="value.val=job">
....
</div>
```

In jobPage.html

```
<div ng-controller="plandingController" ng-repeat="pickedjob in value.val">
```